# Web Scraping Education Data in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Was presented a problem at work and am trying to think / work my way through it. However, I am very new at web scraping, and need some help, or just good starting points, on web scraping.

I have a website from the education commission.

http://ecs.force.com/mbdata/mbprofgroupall?Rep=DEA

This site contains 50 tables, one for each state, with two columns in a question / answer format.  My first attempt has been this...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(XML)

tibble(url = "http://ecs.force.com/mbdata/mbprofgroupall?Rep=DEA") %>% 
  mutate(get_data = map(.x = url,
                        ~GET(.x))) %>% 
  mutate(list_data = map(.x = get_data,
                         ~readHTMLTable(doc=content(.x, "text")))) %>% 
  pull(list_data)
```

My first thought was to create multiple dataframes, one for each state, in a list format.

This idea does not seem to have worked as anticipated.  I was expecting a list, but it seems like a list of on response rather than 50. It appears that this one response read each line, but did not differentiate from one table to the next.  Confused on next steps, anyone with any ideas?  Web Scraping is odd to me.

Second attempt was to copy and paste the table into R as a tribble, one state at a time.  This sort of worked, but not every column is formatted the same way.  Attempted to use `tidyr::separate()` to break up the columns by "/t" and that worked for some columns, but not all.

Any help on this problem, or even just where to look to learn more about web scraping, would be very helpful.  This did not seem all the difficult at first, but seems like there are a couple of things I am am missing. Maybe rvest? Have never used it, but know it is common with web scraping activities.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the desired output format?

Comment: My first thought was to build out a list-column with every table nested.  Another thought, was a tibble of 50 rows, and a nested list column of education data, one for each state. Although, a single table, with with each row identified by state works well too.  That is the solution worked out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already guessed `rvest` is a very good choice for web scraping. Using `rvest` you can get the table from your desired website in just two steps. With some additional data wrangling this could be transformed in a nice data frame.

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(tidyverse)

html <- read_html("http://ecs.force.com/mbdata/mbprofgroupall?Rep=DEA")

df <- html %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE, header = FALSE) %>% 
  .[[1]] %>% 
  # Remove empty rows and rows containing the table header
  filter(!(X1 == "" & X2 == ""), !(grepl("^Dual", X1) & grepl("^Dual", X2))) %>% 
  # Create state column 
  mutate(is_state = X1 == X2, state = ifelse(is_state, X1, NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(state) %>% 
  filter(!is_state) %>% 
  select(-is_state)
head(df, 2)
#>                               X1
#> 1      Statewide policy in place
#> 2 Definition or title of program
#>                                                                                                                                                                  X2
#> 1                                                                                                                                                               Yes
#> 2 Dual Enrollment – Postsecondary Institutions. High school students are allowed to take college courses for credit either at a high school or on a college campus.
#>     state
#> 1 Alabama
#> 2 Alabama
```

Comment: This is a great start, and provides a good answer! and you're right, a little more wrangling creates very nice dataframe / tibble.  Where can I learn more about web scraping?  It does not come up often at work, but it is nice to know whenever it does.